# Will my App Script source expose to client if i let them import my API key?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am planning to create a cloud app (mini SaaS platform) using Google Clould. Clients/Tenants are all running their services with Google App Script (and the core logic are from my library file, which i will share my API ID, e.g. abcDEFGHi....1234...)

But since my DB credentials are stored inside the API file (my library App Script), my concern is will they able to view my app script source code and my login credential expose to them??

I created a mysuite.gs and published as API executable.
I passed the API id to my client (or my test account)

sample app script as below ....

```
var connectionName = 'example.com';
var rootPwd = 'root...';
var user = 'weiliesx';
var userPwd = '1Password';
var db = 'mydb';
var root = 'root';
var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName;
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;
...
```

I am consider myself not a app script security guru, so i yet to hack the app script's credential (so is safe to share my app script API id with DB credential inside?).

But i would like to be very sure no one can hack the credential stored in app script before make my code into production

Comment: If they have the project key, which is used for the library, then there is a way to see the library code.   It can be discovered through the debug window by stepping into the code.  Even if your API key were not hard coded in your library, but stored in script properties, or externally, there could still be a problem.  If someone can see the library code, then they can see the code that retrieves the key.  If they don't have the project key, then that's different.  I'm assuming that you are giving people the key to install a library.

Comment: Then what could be the most efficient way to share my LOGIC instead of letting them to view my code (with DB credential). At first i thought sharing API ID allow them to call out my functions which connect to my cloud DB (with mutiple client details), but if they are able to view my DB login in my app script, then is a security breach :(

Comment: You could use your script project as an intermediary between your clients and your database, and allow the clients to connect to your script by having a `doPost(e)` function in your code.  Their code will make a POST request to your file.  Your file won't be shared with anyone, so they can't see the code.  But in that situation,  quota is being used on your account.  If someone installs a library, the library runs under the authority of the user, using up their quota.  So, your choice is between security and using up your quota.  If the client could use a Google Form or Sheet as the platform,

Comment: then you could provide them with an add-on, which will protect your code.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a way of providing an app to a user, and have the app run under their authority and use up their quota and services, but also protect your code.  Someone needs to pay for the services.